# need confirmation about security with https, jwt and bcrypt

Tags: ssl, https, jwt, bcrypt

I have some question about the security in a login/authentication app :

- if i send a password via `https` is he encrypted by my publickey ?
- if it's the case can I perfectly transmit what I want in clear in my https request without fear of worries? Is it a good practice?
- actually  i use jwt like this, is it ok ? :

  - the user gives an username and a password
  - my front makes a `https` post request with the username and the password (plain text)
  - my back checks if the user exist
  - if it's the case my back makes a `bcrypt.compare` whit the plain text password give by the user and the encrypted password given by the db
  - if it's ok my back send a jwt
- a simple `http` to `https` redirect in my virtualhost is enough for avoid the plaintext transmission ?

Comment: I would not redirect http to https. It is better to let the request fail so that the client recognizes that the wrong protocol is used. Keep in mind that the first http request may already contain the password therefore redirecting it is way too late as the password was then already transmitted in plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS is not a silver bullet, or more precisely the TLS part of it that is relevant to your question.

In the sense that it needs to be correctly configured and deployed.

So, if everything is right, then YES, everything sent (or received for that matter) through HTTPS is encrypted, be it a password, a token, a text, etc. Not by "your publickey" as things are more complicated than that, but to summarize: certificates are used at the beginning of the handshake to provide authentication, after that some session keys are computed and will be used to encrypt any data exchanged.

But it has to be correctly configured: the HTTPS server needs to have a proper valid certificate **AND** the client needs to verify it at each start of handshake. This is often when things start to fall apart as if it is not done properly (or worse: you just not validate the remote certificate and accept any) you are basically encrypting something to an unknown (not guaranteed) remote, so loosing in fact all useful properties of TLS.

Then it seems you are mixing security in transport vs security at rest: you can exchange a password with HTTPS, it is encrypted during transport, great. But when it arrives at remote end, what does the remote do with it? Does it use it just for a computation and then discard it or does it store it elsewhere? If it has to store the password, then you need security at rest: a way to store the password so that even if someone manage to access it then they will not be able to go back to the real plain text password. How you do that depends for what the password is used but if it is for classical authentication needs, indeed you have to look towards bcrypt/scrypt/argon and more generally what is called PBKDF2. Do not listen to people telling that you just have to hash the password, the problem is larger than that.

As for "a simple http to https redirect in my virtualhost is enough for avoid the plaintext transmission ? " probably not but your question lack details.
The client has to send its query before learning that it is a redirection. If in the query there was sensitive information already in some payload, then this will be sent in plain text, and then again maybe later encrypted when switched to HTTPS.

So obviously not something to do. Nowadays you could even just ditch HTTP completely and just listen on HTTPS, specifically if it is for application to application traffic, no need to maintain an HTTP listener.

Comment: Thanks for this good precision; 
``the client needs to verify it at each start of handshake.`` Is it done alone (in case I have a https domain via certbot for example) ? (For my culture) is there a way to ensure this verification ?
For the security at rest i use bcrypt (when registering a user).

Comment: Any good TLS library, hopefully with sane defaults or at least not called with explicit parameters letting it reduce the security, will handle the TLS handshake with the exchange of certificates and the client part will check the server certificate (its internal metadata like dates, its signature, who is the issuer, etc.). You can easily test your client: change your server certificate, including one valid but for another hostname and double check the client part is indeed detecting the problem and blocking the access.